# Quicksort with duplicate values

Tags: java, duplicates, quicksort

I have this java code for QuickSort that works if there are no duplicates, however if there are any duplicates, the QuickSort fails. For example, if I want to QuickSort {5,3,3,1,7} my code will output {1,3,3,7,5}, and I can't seem to figure out why this is the case.

```
 public static void quickSort(Integer[] nums) {
    quickSort(nums, 0, nums.length-1);
}

private static void quickSort(Integer[] ary, int lo, int hi) {
    //pick num @ lo to be pivot
    int pivot = lo;
    int i = lo+1;
    int j = hi;


    if( lo==hi) {
        return;
    }

    while(i <j) {

        if(ary[i].compareTo(ary[pivot]) <=0  ) {
            i++;

        }
        else if(ary[j].compareTo(ary[pivot]) >=0 ) {
            j--;
        }
        else {
            int temp = ary[i];  
            ary[i] = ary[j];
            ary[j] = temp;

        }

    }
    if(i == hi && j == hi) {
        if(ary[pivot].compareTo(hi) > 0) {
            int temp = ary[pivot];
            ary[pivot] = ary[hi];
            ary[hi] = temp;
            pivot = hi;

        }
        else {
            int temp1 = ary[pivot];
            ary[pivot] = ary[i-1];
            ary[i-1] = temp1;
            pivot = i-1;

        }

    }
    if(lo < pivot -1) {
        quickSort(ary, lo, pivot-1);
    }

    if(pivot +1 < hi) {
        quickSort(ary, pivot+1, hi);
    }

}
```

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't look like quicksort. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have modified your code, please check corresponding comments

```
private static void quickSort(Integer[] ary, int lo, int hi) {
//pick num @ lo to be pivot
int pivot = lo;
int i = lo+1;
int j = hi;

if( lo==hi) {
    return;
}

//while(i <j) {
for(;;){//change from while to infinite for
    while(ary[i].compareTo(ary[pivot]) <=0 && i<hi ) {//changed from if to while with boundary conditions
        i++;

    }
    while(ary[j].compareTo(ary[pivot]) >0 && j>lo) { //change from if to while with boundary conditions and it is not >=0 only >
        j--;
    }
    if(i<j){ //changed from else to if
        int temp = ary[i];  
        ary[i] = ary[j];
        ary[j] = temp;

    }else{//added else block
      break;
   }
}
//you didn't handled i>j condition properly i.e when i>j you need to swap pivot and i-1
int temp1 = ary[pivot];
    ary[pivot] = ary[i-1];
    ary[i-1] = temp1;
    pivot = i-1;
//Not required
/*if(i == hi && j == hi) {
    if(ary[pivot].compareTo(hi) > 0) {
        int temp = ary[pivot];
        ary[pivot] = ary[hi];
        ary[hi] = temp;
        pivot = hi;

    }
    else {
        int temp1 = ary[pivot];
        ary[pivot] = ary[i-1];
        ary[i-1] = temp1;
        pivot = i-1;

    }

}*/

if(lo < pivot -1) {
    quickSort(ary, lo, pivot-1);
}

if(pivot +1 < hi) {
    quickSort(ary, pivot+1, hi);
 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to quicksort use the algorithm from this site.

[Quicksort](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort)

It works for me and the explanation is quite good I think.